# Touch command. permission denied

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions, permission-denied

I was able to connect to my school server via SSH. I had an assignment in which I was supposed to use the touch command to create a new file. Yet it keeps returning permission denied. Others were able to do the same thing. Though why do I keep getting this error?

Below is what was the input from the terminal.

```
Last login: Tue Aug 23 09:16:18 on ttys000
Dominiks-Air:~ fsociety95$ ssh djaneka1@navajo.dtcc.edu
djaneka1@navajo.dtcc.edu's password: 
Last login: Tue Aug 23 09:16:35 2016 from pool-72-94-210-193.phlapa.fios.verizon.net
```

Navajo is Linux shell server provided to staff, faculty, and students.  The
operating system is RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.

Alpine, a Pine replacement, has been provided as a mail client.  Run "pine" 
at the command prompt.

This server also provides web space to users.  Web pages can be stored in
the ~/www directory.  This is also accessible by mapping a drive in Windows
to \navajo\homepage.  The URL for your homepage is 
http://user.dtcc.edu/~username/.

Your home directory is also accessible in Windows by mapping to 
\navajo\.

If something appears broken or missing, please email path@dtcc.edu.

Could not chdir to home directory /u/d/j/djaneka1: No such file or directory

```
-bash-3.2$ touch today
touch: cannot touch `today': Permission denied
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/
-bash-3.2$ touch today
touch: cannot touch `today': Permission denied
-bash-3.2$
```

---

Edit: here is the result of `ls -al`

```
-bash-3.2$ ls -al
total 204
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 22 16:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 22 16:50 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Aug  3 14:01 .autofsck
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     0 Jan 30  2009 .autorelabel
-rw-------   1 root root  2050 Aug  3 14:00 .bash_history
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 May  4 04:14 bin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  3072 Aug  3 13:57 boot
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4060 Aug  3 14:02 dev
drwxr-xr-x  87 root root 12288 Aug 23 10:05 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct  1  2009 home
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root 12288 Jun  1 04:09 lib
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Mar 24  2008 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct  1  2009 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     0 Aug  3 14:02 misc
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 May 26  2012 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root     0 Aug  3 14:02 net
drwxr-xr-x   9 root root  4096 Jan  5  2009 nsr
drwxrwxr-x   3 root root  4096 Oct 12  2015 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 219 root root     0 Aug  3 14:01 proc
drwxr-x---  12 root root  4096 Apr 22 10:06 root
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Aug  4 04:02 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  1  2009 selinux
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Oct  1  2009 srv
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root     0 Aug  3 14:01 sys
drwxrwxrwt  38 root root  4096 Aug 23 10:07 tmp
drwxr-xr-x  34 root root  4096 Jun 21 08:29 u
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 Apr 16  2010 usr
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Apr 16  2010 var
-rw-------   1 root root  2865 Dec 16  2008 .viminfo
-bash-3.2$
```

---

EDIT:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLWc2.png) is what I see after trying `touch today` in `/home`

Comment: You don't have permissions to write on the root directory. I suppose you have there an already created directory with your name on which you have the necessary permissions no?

Comment: No. I don't have permissions for the root directory. Although there does seem to be a folder with my name. Although I can't seem to access it.

Comment: Have you tried cd <your_directory_name>?

Comment: please use ls -al and show us the result of that command here with an edit on your question

Comment: I tried copied and pasting the result of ls -al. All directories appear as root.

Comment: please show the output of ls -al

Comment: ok thanks. Check out my answer then ;)

Comment: I suggest scrubbing this question to remove identifying information (school domain, home IP), but after 7.5 years it may not be that important...

Answer (score 2):

So to try and create a new document in the root directory you need to be recognised as root. That means using the `sudo` command.
However for that you would need a password that you may not have. If you do perfect. But in any case I would not recommend adding files to the root directory.
Instead try the following:

```
cd home
touch today
```

This should work just fine and answer your question.

Still if you need/want to create `today` in your root directory try the following

```
sudo touch today
```

You will then be prompted for the root password that you can type (if you have it obviously)

In any case I suggest reading [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions) which may be very helpful for you.

Comment: I keep getting permission denied. It seems I would have my own folder but it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: @user6748110 You're getting the permission denied in your home directory? I believe you're already at there root directory of your own session so you won't find anything with your name. You should be able to touch today in your /home/. I tried touch today on my root directory and I get permission denied as well but I can easily touch today after I have cd'ed in my home directory.

Comment: When I go to the home directory, it won't let me. Others were able to create a file using touch although I'm not sure if something is wrong on my end. If I'm able to log in using my e-mail, shouldn't I have my own folder? I'm just not sure what else to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help though.

Comment: @user6748110 please update your question with what you have just tried. And include everything please: all the commands and all their results.

Comment: @user6748110 so I check your image. Did you get connected with your credentials in the first place? To me it appears as if you were not properly connected

Comment: @user6748110 any news?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this was ever truly answered.
If I was looking at it, I would try to see what the system thinks is the home directory of djaneka1, since it may have been setup partway and not completed, leaving stuff owned by root that should have been owned by djaneka1.

If you use the pwd command, and get back the "/" (root) directory there is something wrong with your setup.

**The message: Could not chdir to home directory /u/d/j/djaneka1: No such file or directory**
tells you it can't find your home directory.

**-bash-3.2$ pwd
/**

the command "pwd" revealing "/" is just an artifact of the system not being able to find your home directory.

To find what the system thinks is one's home directory,
one can search the file named '/etc/passwd' for one's login name.
I expect this is a possible result if you do that:

**$ fgrep 'djaneka1' /etc/passwd
djaneka1:x:1505:1506::/u/d/j/djaneka1:/bin/bash**

since it complained that it couldn't find that directory.
This needs to be fixed by someone who has more rights to the system, like root.
there is nothing **djaneka1** can do a